# Conan conflict in libpng/1.6.34@bincrafters/stable on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, zlib, libpng, conan

I cannot install all my project dependencies on **Windows** using conan. This error occurs each time when I do `conan install . --build`:

```
ERROR: Conflict in libpng/1.6.34@bincrafters/stable
Requirement zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable conflicts with already defined zlib/1.2.11 
To change it, override it in your base requirements
```

My conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
boost/1.69.0@conan/stable
sfml/[>=2.5.0]@bincrafters/stable

[options]
sfml:window=True
sfml:graphics=True
sfml:audio=True
sfml:network=True
sfml:shared=True

[generators]
cmake

[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./bin
lib, *.dylib* -> ./bin
lib, *.lib -> ./bin
```

Work perfectly on Linux. Someone can see a problem ?

Comment: The packages using ``user/channel`` are becoming deprecated. Some packages are already using new dependencies, like ``zlib/1.2.11`` and some other still using the old ones ``zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable``. The package recipes might use different requirements in different platforms, and some might not have updated yet. Try to use ``boost/1.69.0`` as requirement, not with the ``conan/stable``. If the ``sfml`` package is not there yet, it would be worth asking for it (or try to contribute it) in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index.

Comment: as the error message says, you can try to override this requirement for zlib by defining it your conanfile: add `zlib/1.2.11` to your conanfile and try to install again

Comment: @drodri zlib/1.2.11 is different than zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable even if it's the same version ?

Comment: @DevHugo yes, it is a different package with a different recipe. Most likely it is totally compatible for the consumer, because it package the same library, with the same version, and the newer "zlib/1.2.11" is basically an evolution of "zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable" to be built automatically by the conan-center-index. But they are different packages.