# conan dependency conflict when importing package hdf5/1.10.6 which depends on zlib/1.2.11

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management, hdf5, conan

I try to add the package hdf5/1.10.6 in my application. I've got the following error.

```
[build] ERROR: Conflict in hdf5/1.10.6
[build]     Requirement zlib/1.2.11 conflicts with already defined zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
[build]     To change it, override it in your base requirements
[build] CMake Error at build/conan.cmake:402 (message):
[build]   Conan install failed='1'
[build] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[build]   build/conan.cmake:497 (conan_cmake_install)
[build]   CMakeLists.txt:12 (conan_cmake_run)
```

There is an existing package that depends on 'zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable'. And hdf5/1.10.5 depends on 'zlib/1.2.11'.

How can I resolve this conflict? Is there a way to specify zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable = zlib/1.2.11?

thx

Comment: See the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928441/conan-conflict-in-libpng-1-6-34bincrafters-stable-on-windows for an explanation and a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Conan Center Index is available, the original recipes from Conan Center has been migrated. However, a new change occurred to keep all recipes references simpler, both username and channel (namespace) were removed. There is a detailed explanation on [CCI's Wiki](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/wiki#more-information-about-recipes).

You have to follow the message instruction: "To change it, override it in your base requirements"

Replace the Conan reference zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable from your project, to zlib/1.2.11.  Besides that, zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable is deprecated, and won't receive any new update.

If you are interested in finding more available packages from CCI, you can search on [Conan Center website](https://conan.io/center/), or just running the Conan [search command](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/search.html).